# Ads on Code Review

Tags: discussion

Looks like Code Review was selected for [enabling ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287242/were-enabling-display-ads-on-select-stack-exchange-sites). Does anyone know when this goes live? Right now I run adblock, but I might as well turn it off when this comes.

Comment: Within 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @Mast on a continual basis, right?

Comment: Oh, you'll probably get the same answer in another 6-8 weeks.

Comment: More serious, the closest thing I've heard to an implementation date is 'soon'. So, I don't have a clue and I'd be surprised if any of us knew more.

Comment: I've heard from Tim Post to expect ads on CR around mid-this-week: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287242/were-enabling-display-ads-on-select-stack-exchange-sites#comment932338_287242

Comment: I've already seen ads on Code Review. I'm not sure if it was just a test, or if was the "real" thing.

Comment: I've seen them already as @200_success said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT they're live already.

[image: some Microsoft ad]

Not sure since when, but they're live.